# python re regex

Tags: python, regex

I have a string:

```
A = '\r\nGigabitEthernet1/0/26  unassigned      YES unset  down                  down    \r\nGigabitEthernet1/0/27  unassigned      YES unset  down                  down    \r\nGigabitEthernet1/0/28  unassigned      YES unset  down                  down    \r\nSW-P-24#                                       '
```

My regex is

```
r'\\r?\\n?.{0,100}\s{0,40}$'
```

My goal is to replace `'\r\nSW-P-24#                                       '` with `'\\r\\n'`

so my code is

```
re.sub(r'\s*\\r?\\n?.{0,100}\s{0,40}$', '\\r\\n', A)
```

My expect return is

```
'\r\nGigabitEthernet1/0/26  unassigned      YES unset  down                  down    \r\nGigabitEthernet1/0/27  unassigned      YES unset  down                  down    \r\nGigabitEthernet1/0/28  unassigned      YES unset  down                  down    \r\n'
```

but Python returns:

```
'\r\nGigabitEthernet1/0/26  unassigned      YES unset  down                  down    \r\nGigabitEthernet1/0/27  unassigned      YES unset  down                  down    \r\nGigabitEthernet1/0/28  unassigned      YES unset  down                  down    \r\nSW-P-24#                                       '
```

What is the right code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lies around `\\r?\\n?`

First, the raw prefix doesn't require double slashes, and then the "0 or 1" flag confuses regex engine.

Using backwards lookup on the CR+LF group seems to work (and that trick allows to replace by empty string instead of repeating the CR+LF string):

```
re.sub(r'(?<=\r\n).{0,100}\s{0,40}$', '', A)
```

however, I'm not sure that don't you want to just remove the last line, in that case, no regex needed:

```
"\r\n".join(A.split("\r\n")[:-1])
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
B = re.sub(  r'\r\n\S+\s+$',   r'\r\n',   A  )
```

The main thing to fix was that you should **either** use a raw-string `r'...'`,  **or** you double up every backslash to `'\\'`—but don't do both of these things together.

I've then chosen to the matching pattern after the last CRLF as `\S+` which means "one or more non-space characters" followed by `\s+` which means "one or more whitespace characters".   Your approach `.{0,100}\s{0,40}` may work, although the interpretation and debugging is a little confounded because `.` *also* matches white-space.   I have a feeling you may need to be more specific than either of these approaches, however—it depends what other examples you need to match and what the rule really is.  The `?` marks that you attempted to place after `\r` and `\n` suggest to me that there's more that you're not telling us. (The target line-to-remove, and the CRLF that precedes it, might not be there at all, for example? If that's the case, it will need to be tweaked further.)

Answer (score 0):

This regex will solve your problem

```
re.sub('\s*.{0,100}\s{0,40}$', 'viki', A)
```

Issues with your regex is that

`\\r?` looks for `\\` and then r is optional. Which is not what you are looking for. Same applies for `\\n?`

The reason the regex I suggested works is because your .{0,100} is already consuming the `\r\n` as 4 different character values.